# ERROR AL USAR: php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Tengo un error al ejecutar el comando "php artisan migrate".

Ya cree la base de datos en el phpMyAdmin de XAMPP, la misma obviamente no tiene tablas creadas.

El error que me da en la terminal es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente con "php artisan cache:clear" pero tambien me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según leí por allí que como la carpeta **storage/framework/cache/data** no estaba creada tenía que hacerlo manual, pues tambien lo hice y sigue el error.

Por favor, en lo que puedan ayudarme les agradezco.

Gracias a todos de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Revisa tu archivo `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=prueba
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=`
```

En la raíz del proyecto y verifica que la base de datos `DB_DATABASE` existe en tus bases de datos, en tu caso `prueba`

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero aun nada. La Base de Datos "prueba" si la tengo creada. Yo le cambié el puerto a MySQL por ello lo tengo así DB_PORT=3636. Esto debido a que el 3306 lo tengo ocupado con MAMP. La verdad no sé que pueda estar pasando

Comment: Te recomiendo que:
Verifiques La conexión a base de datos (Host, clave, usuario)
Ver el orden de las migraciones y fechas aveces es necesario
Verifica por que te dice que no tienes la base de datos creadas si está creada, seguramente es el puerto o algún dato de conexión, saludos

Comment: Buenos días. Solucione hace unos días pero se olvidó volver para comentar a todos. Lo que hice fue volver a colocar los puertos predeterminados en XAMPP, tanto en el panel como en los archivos .conf obviamente y cambié los puertos en MAMP para que no usará los mismos. A partir de allí ya todo funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo `php.ini` reemplaza la linea que pone `;extension=pdo_mysql` por `extension=pdo_mysql`.

Comment: por que? que tiene que ver con el error que le aparece?

Comment: si revisas la zona de comentarios, el OP ya resolvió su problema y no es esto que comentas, por favor profundiza en tu aporte

Comment: Tiene todo que ver, lo que hizo él fue regresar todo a como viene por defecto, esa no es una solución optima aunque haya resuelto su problema.

Comment: No amigo tómate el tiempo de ver el error que añade en sus imágenes y esto no tiene relación

Comment: Los "exception trace" 1 y 2 lo dicen... PDOexception y el construct.

Comment: Ese exception no va vinculado a tu aporte, el fallo ahí dice no encontrar la base de datos que es distinto

Answer (score 0):

Debes revisar que la Base de Datos prueba exista dentro de tu servidor de base de datos, ya que el `migrate` intenta correr las migraciones en la base de datos que le configuraste en el archivo de variables `.env`.

Si estas usando algún WAMP/MAMP/XAMP puedes ir a tu phpmyadmin y crear la base con el modo gráfico.

Answer (score 0):

Problemas asociados a eso:

1. Que no exista la BD.
2. Que no tengas permisos para cachear y para acceder a ciertos ficheros dentro del propio proyecto para su correcto funcionamiento.

Prueba a borrar la carpeta vendor manualmente. Luego haz `composer install` y un `composer dump autoload`.

Luego cp .env.example .env y reconfigura tu fichero .env.
Y luego haz un PHP artisan config:caché.

Finalmente un PHP `artisan migrate`.

También prueba a borrar bootstrap/cache